# ASP.NET shared hosting provider that allows multiple websites (not just applications)?

Tags: asp.net, hosting

Most ASP.NET hosts give you a single website in IIS.  Then, they let you set subfolders as applications.  Are there any shared ASP.NET 3.5 hosts that give you multiple websites with a single account?

I have several low traffic websites that don't use much bandwidth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebHost4Life offers this, though there's a small charge per domain. ($15/year or so). I'm sure most hosts can do this, but fees vary.

Comment: Wow, I was downvoted for this? What a capricious world we live in.

Answer (score 1):

I use [ReliableSite.net](http://reliablesite.net/) for a handful of low traffic web sites. Their cheapest shared hosting plan offers unlimited hosted domains, unlimited virtual directories, and a very reasonable amount of bandwidth and storage.

Regardless of who you choose, one feature you want to look for is [DotNetPanel](http://www.dotnetpanel.com/) as the control panel, which ReliableSite does. DotNetPanel offers an experience very close to using the IIS manager itself and exposes nearly all of the options. It also gives you much better control over the file system structure.

One thing to be aware of with ReliableSite, and *any* shared hosting site I presume, is that if your site gets a spike of traffic it could go offline way too easily. Some java bot was continuously crawling one of my sites and spiked the CPU usage over the preset limit. That being said, ReliableSite upped the CPU limit for me once I explained what was happening.

Comment: @John In a basic plan http://reliablesite.net/v3/shared.asp, what kind of trust(full, medium) do these sites run

Answer (score 0):

I find that for low bandwidth websites that the lower end packages at http://www.vpsland.com/ezwin.html You get the control of Remote Desktop and loading pretty much anything you want starting at $18.  The only issue I had with them was their support was a bit slow, and their connection seemed slower than most.

I then switched to MaximumASP with one of their VPS's.  I absolutely love MaximumASP, their support was great and their servers are speedy.  The only issue I have with them is I can't use MySQL, they block it for performance reasons. (use referral id: CRAB-6573)

I have since switched to Mosso (http://www.mosso.com).  I love Mosso.  I don't get the full access via Remote Desktop that I get with my MaximumASP account (which I stil have for my Windows Sharepoint Services sites, and other sites where Remote access is required.).  But, Mosso is fast, has great support, and I can run ASP.NET, PHP, Ruby on Rails, and more all within the same domain, or I can have multiple domains (at no additional cost).  The only issue I have is I found that their description of MSSQL being included was a bit misleading.  I was shocked to find that MSSQL would cost $5 month per database per 500MB of data.  Seems a bit steep.  However, I use NHibernate in all my sites so it was no big deal to convert to MySQL so I went that route and haven't looked back.  If you are interested in Mosso, give them my referral id and you get $100 off your second month.  REF-CODEMONKEY

Another good host is Gate.com.  I found that they were middle of the road as far as performance.  But their support was great, and the price was right.

The one host I would avoid is 1&1.com.  I made the stupid mistake of registering my domain with their "FREE" offer.  I then found that I did not have the control I needed for file system rights.  I cancelled the account within 30 days and got my money back.  However, my domain ended up on the auction block.  I still have not gotten the domain back.  They keep paying for it.  It was a very good domain (only 5 characters), but I have to chalk it up as a stupid mistake (which I knew better, I was just being cheap).